# Eclipse wont start if I increase memory parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, heap-memory

in order to remove my java heap space error i set the parameter in eclipse.ini to be:

```
old param : 
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

new param
-Xms40m
-Xmx2000m
```

I tried to increase a little space but i still was getting the same heap space error , so i thought to increase it even further but then eclipse fails to start saying

```
FAILED TO CREATE THE JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE
```

Comment: What OS are you using (32 or 64 bit) and what JRE/JDK version?

Comment: Please share you OS details. Is it 32bit or 64 ?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: i am using jdk 1.7 64 bit , OS is also 64 bit , and my RAM is 8 GB

Comment: I´d suggest to look at memory consumption first before maximizing the heap. Often, you will only postpone a memory leak´s symptoms if you blindly extend the heap in response getting an "out of space" error situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size you request via -Xmx must be allocateable as a single block by the OS. If this is possible the usable maximum depends on OS and VM implementation details.

For 32 bit-systems, see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.igaa%2F_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html for "exact" limits. There, they state that on 64 bit-systems, the limit depends solely upon what the OS can support in theory, and in practice (largest continuous available block is the upper limit).

Comment: Can you please share some reference for this ?

Comment: This is not true. On my machine with 8GB RAM, I've allocated 4GB to Eclipse and it works.

Comment: OK seems to be VM vendor dependent.

Comment: @TheBlastOne : I am using 8 GB ram this means i can use up to 2 GB ryt ??

Comment: Maybe. It depends on OS, VM, 32 vs 64 bits. And the OS must be able to allocate one continuous block for the heap. Insofar my original answer is wrong.